# Right Align Text at end of line without table

Tags: html, css, layout

I spent a little while trying to figure out how to achieve the following effect without using a table but couldn't figure it out: http://jsfiddle.net/sKFzA/

CSS :

```
.header{width:100%;font:25px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}
.titleCol{width:99%;}
.dateCol{vertical-align:bottom;white-space:nowrap;}
.dateText{font-size:12px;}
```

HTML :

```
<table class="header">
<tr>
    <td class="titleCol">This is the blog title</td>
    <td class="dateCol"> <span>&nbsp;</span><span class="dateText">1/23/2012</span>

    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

To explain it, I have a blog title and a blog date. The title could be long and wrap. At the end of the last line, wrapped or not, I want the blog date to be aligned to the right.

So I have two questions. Is there any reason not to use a table for this? If so, how would you achieve it without assuming static font sizes?

Comment: What you are calling 'dateRow' and 'titleRow' are usually called 'columns' because they are left and right of each other.

Comment: Tables should not be used for layout purposes, they're only for tabular data.

Comment: @cimmanon Everyone says that yet so often there is no alternative or the alternative is ridiculously convoluted and therefore unmaintainable. But that's why I ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of cimmanon and the others, I've gathered that:

1. The only reason's not to use a table here is because layout is not technically a table's intended purpose and also by not using a table you can separate your layout (CSS) from your markup (HTML). However, if I were to use a table, I am not aware of of any negative effects.
2. There doesn't seem to be a good solution to this exact layout without the concept of table, but my table solution can be achieved without using an HTML table by applying styles to display other elements as the table. So I replaced my table elements with divs. The span with the space before the date allows the smaller sized date to stay aligned to the title's baseline without having to hard-code line height's or font sizes. So if the font sizes change, I don't have to worry about updating any other magic numbers hard-coded around them.

http://jsfiddle.net/K35gT/

HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="titleCol">This is the blog title</div>
    <div class="dateCol">
        <span>&nbsp;</span><span class="dateText">1/23/2012</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
.header{display:table;width:100%;font:25px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}
.titleCol{display:table-cell;width:99%;}
.dateCol{display:table-cell;vertical-align:bottom;white-space:nowrap;}
.dateText{font-size:12px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS has properties that allow any element to behave like specific components of a table.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/rjiesryc

```
<header>
  <h1>This is the blog title</h1>
  <time datetime="2012-01-23">1/23/2012</time>
</header>
```

CSS

```
 header {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
    }

    header h1, header time {
      display: table-cell;
    }

    header time {
      /*vertical-align: bottom;*/
    }
```

Comment: Thanks cimmanon. Does it not require a table-row element around the table-cell elements? Why is this appraoch of telling the browser to treat elements like a table a better practice than using an actual table? Because it separates the layout from the markup?

Comment: A table-row element is optional when done this way.  If you omit it, an anonymous one is created for you.  Tables, just like most other tags, have special meaning and should only be used for their intended purpose.  I mean, why do you use a h1 for your title?  Why not use a paragraph or a div?  Not tying your markup to its appearance is just an added bonus.

Comment: True, but in reality, tables work and historically, other layouts did not thanks to IE. Now that they're getting their act together and following CSS standards, I think this is becoming more realistic. I agree with you, that's just too often been stated without an accompanying solution. Back _to_ the solution, how can you edit this so that the date's baseline is aligned with the title's bottom baseline when wrapped?

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll have to know the font-sizes to get your elements to line up along the baseline.  http://cssdeck.com/labs/hhg4imdz

Answer (score 0):

You do not need tables at all, simply block elements with the right styles.

If it was my website, I would do this:

```
<header>
  <h1>This is the blog title</h1>
  <time datetime="2012-01-23">1/23/2012</time>
</header>
```

Combined with this CSS:

```
header {position:relative; width:100%; font:25px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}
header > h1 {margin:0px;}
header > time {display:block; font-size:12px; text-align:right;}
```

You can decide if you want to use HTML5 elements, or general elements and if you want to hook in class names or not. Here's the jsFiddle for above: http://jsfiddle.net/sKFzA/13/

Comment: Instead of the aside, you could use `<time>`.

Comment: Thanks rgthree. That's not the same though because the date is on it's own line instead of on the last line of the title.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? I hope i got you right.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="titleRow">This is the blog title</div>
<div id="dateText"><span id="spandate">1/23/2012</span></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
   #titleRow{width:80%; height: 25px; font:25px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; 
   float:left;text-align: left;}
   #dateText{width:20%; height: 25px; font-size:12px;float:left; text-align: right; position: relative;}
   #spandate { position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/sKFzA/31/

Comment: Similar, but the problem here is the date is aligned to the top. I want it aligned to the baseline of the title's bottom line. Try resizing my fiddle so the text wraps to see what I mean. Thanks!

Comment: I edited this, try this one [http://jsfiddle.net/sKFzA/31/](http://jsfiddle.net/sKFzA/31/)

Comment: Thank you, still pretty different though. The baselines are not lined up. I achieved it by adding the span containing a space with the same font size as the title. Also if you cause this to wrap, the date still stays on the first line. And it's not using the full available width.